# PHP / Laravel - Using Python to image manipulation

Tags: python, php, image, laravel

I have a simple job class in Laravel, that will do the following:

1. Get all the images in a folder `/original`
2. Perform some image manipulation on each image
3. Save each image in a new folder `/preprocessed`

All of these steps are added to a `queue`.

However, I have taken an alternative approach and it is using python to do the actual image manipulation.

This is my code:

```
$images = Storage::allFiles($this->document->path('original'));

foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
    $file = storage_path() . '/app/' . $image; //token/unique_id/original/1.jpg
    $savePath = storage_path() . '/app/' . $this->document->path('preprocessed');

    $filename = $key . '.jpg';

    //Scale and save the image in "/preprocessed"
    $process = new Process("python3 /Python/ScaleImage.py {$file} {$savePath} {$filename}");
    $process->run();

    // executes after the command finishes
    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my python file `ScaleImage.py`, it simply performs some image manipulation and saves the image to the `/preprocessed` folder.

```
    def set_image_dpi(file)
       
        //Image manipulation - removed from example
    
        //save image in /preprocessed
        im.save(SAVE_PATH + FILE_NAME, dpi=(300, 300))
        
        return SAVE_PATH + FILE_NAME
    
    print(set_image_dpi(FILE_PATH))
```

The above code works.

In the future, I might need to do even more image manipulation such as noise removal, skew correction, etc.

My final goal is to use `Tesseract OCR` on the preprocessed image to grab the text content of the image.

Now I am sure I could achieve similar results, for example using `ImageMagick` in PHP.

However, I've read that for image processing and OCR, Python's performance is a lot better.

Is the above approach a good idea? Is there anything that can be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## Anything that can be improved?

This line uses interpolation with [complex (curly) syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

> ```
> $process = new Process("python3 /Python/ScaleImage.py {$file} {$savePath} {$filename}");
> ```

The [simple syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) can be used - i.e. curly braces can be removed

```
$process = new Process("python3 /Python/ScaleImage.py $file $savePath $filename");
```

Though there is an argument to maintain the habit of including curly braces for the times when it is required and also for clarity.

> ## Now I am sure I could achieve similar stuff with for example ImageMagick in PHP.

Yes the [PHP Image Processing and GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php#book.image) has functions like [`imageresolution()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageresolution.php) to set the resolution of an image. It can be used with functions like [`imagecreatefromjpeg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) to create the image object and [`imagejpeq()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) to output the image to a file. And yes there is an ImageMagick function [`Imagick::setImageResolution()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageresolution.php) which could be used instead.